# Select all the nodes which have namespace in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

Hi can anybody help me out. I have a XML which contains my own namespace xmlns:NS . I need to select all the nodes which contains the namespace "NS". How can we do this using C#.net.

I tried like below:

```
XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Path);
XmlNodeList oNodeList=doc.GetElementByTagname("NS:Text");
```

Here i am getting all the nodes which have "NS:Text" namespace.  But I need to select all the nodes like below:

```
XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Path);
XmlNodeList oNodeList=doc.GetElementByTagname("NS");
```

so that i can select all the nodes which contains namespace "NS". but this is not working. How can we achieve this?

Following is my XML format.

```
<xml 1.0 ?>
    <Root xmlns:NS="www.yembi.com">
        <NS:Entry Value="User">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <NS:display type="Label" name="First Name">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <NS:Text type="Text">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <NS:Button Type="SubmitButton" name="submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </NS:Entry>
```

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML instead? It would be very easy then.

Comment: Your sample Xml is not well-formed.

Comment: Your sample Xml is still not well-formed after the edit. As becomes obvious by your formatting, `<Root>` is never closed. Also, `<NS:display>` and other elements are not closed. Moreover, the first line should read `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

Comment: how can do this using LINQ to XML..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression with the [`SelectNodes` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx).

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Path);

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("NS", "www.yembi.com");
XmlNodeList oNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//NS:*", mgr);
```

The XPath expression `//NS:*` selects any element with the `NS` prefix.

One note on your question: `NS` is not a namespace in your Xml document, it is just a namespace prefix. `www.yembi.com` is your namespace.

You can think of the prefix as a local (within the document) placeholder for the namespace that connects the namespace with the identifiers in the document. You can easily change the placeholder in the XPath-related code (e.g. to `x`), and leave the `NS` in the document, and things will still work, as long as it's still the namespace `www.yembi.com`.

Comment: Yeah i tried this also. I am getting count zero in oNodeList. can we do in anyother way..

Comment: @user1493082: Works for me when I test it in an Xml editor after correcting the Xml document from your question. Has the document been correctly loaded? Have you possibly changed the namespace URI?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest LINQ to XML if you've .net framework version 3.5 or higher.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path);

    XNamespace ns = "www.yembi.com";
    var result = doc.Root.Descendants()
                   .Where(p => p.GetPrefixOfNamespace(ns) == "NS");
```